# Change values in a matrix

Tags: r, recode

I have two text files: `ped1.txt` and `ped2.txt`. The field separation character is tab/space.

`ped1.txt`

```
222 333 444
333 458 458
458 774 556
500K lines...
```

`ped2.txt`

```
222 -12006
333 -11998
```

I need to recode the numbers in file 1 using key from file 2, for all data.
Result should be like:

```
-12006 -11998 444
-11998    458 458
   458    774 556
500K lines...
```

How to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: try `mapvalues` in plyr

Comment: Pedigree renumbering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
ped1
#    V1  V2  V3
# 1 222 333 444
# 2 333 458 458
# 3 458 774 556
ped2
#    V1     V2
# 1 222 -12006
# 2 333 -11998
```

You can do either:

```
apply(ped1, c(1,2), function(x) ifelse(x %in% ped2$V1, ped2$V2[ped2$V1 == x], x))
#          V1     V2  V3
# [1,] -12006 -11998 444
# [2,] -11998    458 458
# [3,]    458    774 556
```

or

```
sapply(ped1, function(x) plyr::mapvalues(x, ped2$V1, ped2$V2, FALSE))
#          V1     V2  V3
# [1,] -12006 -11998 444
# [2,] -11998    458 458
# [3,]    458    774 556
```

depending on your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Use as.vector() to convert the first matrix into a vector.

Then use mapvalues() from plyr package or maybe even more efficient use the set() method from data.table package. The set() method requires you to cast to single column data.table after converting to vector.

When the recoding/replacements are done, you can convert back to matrix with method matrix(your_new_vector, ncol=original_number_of_cols).

Have fun